# Naming an AWS EC2 security group IP permissions rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am using the AWS PHP SDK version 3. I am able to create security groups using the API, as well as creating IP Permission rules. What I can't figure out is how give the IP Permissions rule a name.

Here's what I have:

```
$params = 
[
    'Description' => 'My Security Group',
    'GroupName' => 'my_security_group',
    'VpcId' => 'vpc-a9d2h3d7',
    'TagSpecifications' => [
        [
            'ResourceType' => 'security-group',
            'Tags' =>
            [
                ['Key' => 'Name', 'Value' => 'My Security Group']
            ]                
        ]
    ],
];

$Ec2Client->createSecurityGroup($params);
```

At this point the group is created

Then I create an IP Permissions rule:

```
$ip_permissions = [
    'GroupName' => 'my_security_group',
    'FromPort' => 0, 
    'ToPort' => 65535, 
    'IpProtocol' => 'tcp', 
    'IpRanges' => [['CidrIp' => 'xx.xxx.xx.xxxx/32', 'Description' => 'Main Office']],
];

$Ec2Client->authorizeSecurityGroupIngress($ip_permissions);
```

Through the AWS Console, I can see that the rule is created, but the Name column is empty. How do I create the Name through the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be same, by using `TagSpecifications`. But instead of `security-group` you need to have `security-group-rule`:

```
    'TagSpecifications' => [
        [
            'ResourceType' => 'security-group-rule',
            'Tags' =>
            [
                ['Key' => 'Name', 'Value' => 'My Security Group Rule']
            ]                
        ]
    ]
```

Full example in AWS CLI (don't have php):

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress  --group-id sg-00102bde0b55e29fe --ip-permissions FromPort=0,IpProtocol=tcp,IpRanges='[{CidrIp=10.10.10.10/32,Description="Main Office"}]',ToPort=65535 --tag-specifications ResourceType=security-group-rule,Tags='[{Key=Name,Value=MyName}]'
```

Comment: It did not work through PHP. The examples Amazon provides don't use these parameters.

Comment: @EastsideDev There is also a separate call [createTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#createtags) which allows for setting up tags. So if `TagSpecifications` does now work in PHP, you can use the separate call `createTags`.

Comment: Using the createTags call works. It seems weird that things that work for the CLI do not work for the PHP SDK, or are not properly documented.

Comment: @EastsideDev boto3 also works. But on php docs they write `Version: 2016-11-15`. This is very old. Guess PHP does not get too many updates.